# Logarithm to any base of exponential data always linear?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Maybe I'm completely wrong but I don't get it. I calculate the values of $3^n$ in Excel (in a range from $0$ to $30$). Then I take the values and calculate the logarithm of it but to a different base of $2$. When I plot the result I get a linear curve and it doesn't matter if I take as base $3$ or $2$.

So why is the logarithm to any base from a exponential function to any base always a linear function? Or isn't it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is.

First, $\log_a (b)$ is *defined* to be $\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$, where $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm. (You then have to prove that $a^{\log_a b} = b$.)

Let's look at 
$$
\log_a (s^q)
$$
so $s$ is the base you use for exponents ($3$ in your example), and $a$ is the base oyu use for logs ($2$ in your example): 
\begin{align}
\log_a (s^q) &= \frac{\ln s^q}{\ln a} & \text{using the definition}\\
& = \frac{1}{\ln a}  \ln s^q& \text{algebra}\\
& = \frac{1}{\ln a}q \ln s & \text{property of $\ln$}\\
& = \frac{\ln s}{\ln a} q & \text{algebra}
\end{align}
which is just a constant multiple of $q$.

As for the proof that's needed to show that definition is correct, you need to know that for natural logs, $\ln (xy) = \ln x + \ln y$ (the "multiplication rule"), and that if $\ln x = \ln y$, then $x = y$ (the 
"1-1 property"). One consequence of the multiplication rule is that $\ln x/y = \ln x - \ln y ("division rule") and that $\ln x^y = y \ln x$. (Note: all these make sense only when the arguments to $\ln$, on both sides, are positive.)

Let's compare 
$$
a^{\log_a b}
$$
with $b$, by comparing their logarithms. That is, we'll see that 
$$
\ln(a^{\log_a b})
$$
is the same as 
$$
\ln b,
$$
and thus, but the "1-1" property of logs, see that the two are the same.

OK. Well
\begin{align}
\ln(a^{\log_a b})
&= \log_a (b) \cdot \ln(a) & \text{by the power rule} \\
&= \frac{\ln(b)}{\ln (a)} \cdot \ln(a) & \text{by the definition of $\log_a$} \\
&= \ln(b) & \text{by cancellation.} \\
\end{align}

So we've shown that these two numbers have the same natural log, hence (by the 1-1 rule) they are the same.

Comment: Wow thank you for the complete proof! =)

Comment: That's what we're here for. Glad it was of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's just because
$$\log_{b}a^x =x\cdot\underbrace{\log_b a}_{\textrm{constant}}$$(you have $a=3$ and $b=2$) so the graph is of the form $$y=kx$$